# Angular 1.3 Access directive $invalid in template

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have a directive that checks conditions of 3 input fields in the directive's template, and used $setValidity to disable a save button, AND gives one of the fields a color;
In angular 1.2 this works:

```
template: '<input type="text" size="8" ng-model="date.date" ng-change="checkDateInput();" ng-class="{\'ng-invalid\': $invalid}" ui-mask="9999-99-99" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">'
```

We now switched to Angular 1.3, and instead of directly manipulating with $setValidity I made $validators (new in 1.3).

Much more clean, but now adding the class breaks; when I print $error or $invalid in the directive template it doesn't exist, while when I use those outside the directive they give the correct boolean.

Anyone knows how to access the ngModel properties in the template of the directive itself in 1.3?

Answer (score 2):

you are adding wrongly the class:

```
ng-class="{\'ng-invalid\': $invalid}" ui-mask="9999-99-99" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">'
```

should be

```
ng-class="{'ng-invalid': $invalid}" ui-mask="9999-99-99" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">'
```

Also try to put the name of the form before $invalid, like

```
myFormName.$invalid
```

Comment: Because this is part of a directive template the whole thing is between quotes, that's why they need to be escaped... your version crashes on creating the directive.

Comment: ok, but this one will crash when evaluating ng-class, you cant pass classes with dash if without own quotes

Comment: The problem is I can't access $invalid in the directive's template property at all; if I type {{ $invalid }} at the end of the template property it stays empty.